# What is the problem with my code here? problems with if statements and switch cases

Tags: c, console

For this question:

Write a C program that determines the day number (1 to 366) in a year for a date that is provided as input data. As an example, January 1, 1994, is day 1. December 31, 1993, is day 365. December 31, 1996, is day 366, since 1996 is a leap year. A year is a leap year if it is divisible by four, except that any year divisible by 100 is a leap year only if it is divisible by 400. Your program should accept the month, day, and year as integers. Include a function leap that returns 1 if called with a leap year, 0 otherwise.

Example running the code:

Please enter day [1=31], month [1-12], and year [e.g. 2020] as integers:

12 2 2021

Output:

Day Number: 43

I wrote this code but whenever I run it and enter the day, month, and year values, it returns blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int leap_year(int year);
int main()
{
   int day,month,year;
   printf("Enter the date:(DD MM YYYY)\n");
   scanf("%d%d%d",&day,&month,&year);
   if ((day>31 || day<1) || (month<1 || month>12))
       printf("Error! Invalid day or month.\n");

   else
   {
        switch(month)
       {
       case '1':
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day);
           break;
       case '2':
           if ((leap_year(day)==1 && day>29)|| (leap_year(day)==0 && day>28))
               printf("Error! Invalid day.\n");
           else
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+31);
           break;
       case '3':
           if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+60);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+59);
           break;
       case '4':
           if (day>30)
           printf("Error! Invalid day.\n");
           else if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+91);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+90);
           break;
       case '5':
           if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+121);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+120);
           break;
       case '6':
           if (day>30)
           printf("Error! Invalid day.\n");
           else if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+152);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+151);
           break;
       case '7':
           if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+182);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+181);
           break;
       case '8':
           if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+213);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+212);
       case '9':
           if (day>30)
           printf("Error! Invalid day.\n");
           else if (leap_year(year)==1)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+244);
           else if (leap_year(year)==0)
           printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+243);
           break;
       case '10':
            if (leap_year(year)==1)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+274);
            else if (leap_year(year)==0)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+273);
            break;
       case '11':
            if (day>30)
            printf("Error! Invalid day.\n");
            else if (leap_year(year)==1)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+305);
            else if (leap_year(year)==0)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+304);
            break;
       case '12':
            if (leap_year(year)==1)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+335);
            else if (leap_year(year)==0)
            printf("Day Number: %d.\n",day+334);
            break;
       }

   }


}

int leap_year(int year)
{
   int leap_day;
   if
   (year%100==0 && year%400==0)
   {leap_day=1;
   return leap_day;}

   else if(year%4==0)
       {leap_day=1;
   return leap_day;}

   else
       leap_day=0;
   return leap_day;
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: “Except that any year divisible by 100 is a leap year only if it is divisible by 400” wouldn’t this condition be satisfied with “divisible by 4”? Sounds overly convoluted.

Comment: @nico_c No, that's exactly the condition.  1800 and 1900 are not leap years but 2000 is.

Comment: @dbush interesting. Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using characters for your cases instead of numbers:

```
case '1':
```

This is looking for the value which is the encoding for the character `'1'`, which in ASCII is 48.  You instead want:

```
case 1:
```

And similarly for the other cases.

Also, check your logic for leap years for years divisible by 100 but not 400.

On a different note, you've got a *lot* of magic numbers scattered throughout the code.  A better way to implement this would be to reverse the order of the cases and use case fallthrough to add in the number of days for each prior month.  This leaves you with just the number of days in each month in each case, and leaves the leap year check to only February.

Comment: Appreciate the help, it now works fine. Can you elaborate more on the fallthrough and how I could write this code in a better, more efficient way? I am only a beginner in C Programming and I've recently learned if statements and switch cases.

Comment: @OJScofield A `case` doesn't have to have a `break` before the next case.  That will cause the code to continue running the next `case`.